# Excel VBA code to extract data from an HTMLSelect control

Tags: excel, vba, controls, html-select, worksheet

I'm creating a macro that works on an Excel spreadsheet into which has been pasted data from a webpage.  I want to extract information from the spreadsheet.  One piece of information I want is contained in a control (list box, I think).  The worksheet's properties show the control as HTMLSelect1 with type HTMLSelect/HTMLSelect, but when I run the following code:

```
Sub test()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Dim lb As HTMLSelect
   Set lb = ws.HTMLSelect1
End Sub
```

MS VBA says "Compile error:  Method or data member not found".  If I iterate through ws.Shapes the list box comes up as the fifth item, but if I change the last line to

```
   Set lb = ws.Shapes(5)
```

I get a "Type mismatch" error.  How can I access the list box?

Comment: Can you try a `MsgBox (ws.Shapes(5).Name)` just to make sure you are working on the right one?

Comment: @b126 It shows "Control 5"

Comment: The reason I think they are the same is that the control is deleted if I execute "ws.Shapes(5).Delete".

Comment: HTMLSelect1 is listed as an object/property under ws when I expand using the + symbol next to it in the watch window.  How is VB finding that property, and how to I access it?  I'm not too familiar with VBA, but it seems like I'd need to cast the object into a list control if I try to access it as a shape.  Is that possible in VBA?

Comment: Can you expand further this object in the debug mode? I don't get this "HTMLSelect" type in my EXCEL 2016 sorry, that's why I used Variant

Comment: Expanding the HTMLSelect1 item in the watch window shows a bunch more properties, including properties that are recognizable as list box properties, like "DisplayValues" and "Values".  The "DisplayValues" shows the choices in the list box I'm interested in."  Expanding other worksheet objects that don't include this control doesn't show the HTMLSelect1 property.

Answer (score 1):

You will find everything related to this listbox in the underlying object
**lst.DrawingObject.Object**

You can try this piece of code :

```
Sub test()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   
   'Dim lb As HTMLSelect
   'Set lb = ws.HTMLSelect1
   'Set lb = ws.Shapes(0)

   Dim lst As Variant
   Set lst = ws.Shapes(5)
   
   MsgBox (lst.DrawingObject.Object.Name)
   MsgBox (lst.DrawingObject.Object.HTMLName)
   MsgBox (lst.DrawingObject.Object.DisplayValues)
   MsgBox (lst.DrawingObject.Object.Values)

End Sub
```

Comment: The code wouldn't run as currently listed because lst wasn't defined.  I tried using "Dim lst as Shape", but then I get "Run-time error '438':  Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Weird since I don't need to define all my variables under Excel VBA. Can you try with the updated type (Variant) in the meantime? BTW, are you accessing VBA with ALT-F11 in Excel?

Comment: I had "Option Explicit" set at the top of my code.  Getting rid of it allows me to run without defining lst, but then I get the 438 error.  I access VBA through through the "Visual Basic" icon under the "Developer" tab.  I tried with ALT-F11, and it takes me to the same screen.  I also tried with "Dim lst as Variant", with the same result.

Comment: *"Weird since I don't need to define all my variables under Excel VBA."* - that's not weird, that's simply because you refuse to use `Option Explicit`. Why you do that is beyond me.

Comment: @FunThomas Exactly! I've put it a million of times in my old classic asp code but I never even thought of putting it in a VBA excel.